# Connection delay occurs in tslib.es6.js

Tags: firebase, timeout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESllO.png)
Due to excessive loading time delay in tslib.es6.js,
there is a problem in accessing the website currently in service.

Questions

1. When loading firebase-app.js, it seems to refer to tslib.es6.js. I would like to know the role of tslib.es6.js.
2. Intermittent failures occur in tslib.es6.js. Is there a way to not use tslib.es6.js
3. The error in tslib.es6.js only appears in the Chrome browser. It does not appear in Edge browser.

JavaScript code was written as follows.
jQuery.getScript("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js", function () {jQuery.getScript("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js", function () {jQuery.getScript("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-messaging.js", function () {});});});

Connection delay occurs in tslib.es6.js

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)